# How do i process Request & Response from Gwt to PHP and Vice Versa?

Tags: java, php, gwt

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, URL.encode(url));                 
try {
 builder.sendRequest(requestdata, new RequestCallback() {                          

@Override                         
        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {   
        int result = response.getStatusCode();       
        System.out.println(result);        
        }
  @Override
        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {                                                      
        }
        });
 } catch (RequestException ex) {                         
   Logger.getLogger(MainEntryPoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);                       
 }
```

This is My Code to Send Request . 
How Can i process Request and Response According to This Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct.Please check url whether it have port number.You should not mansion your port number in URL.